# IBM mobilefirst cli-installer 7.0.0 zip file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am searching for an alternative download link for mobilefirst-cli-installer-7.0.0.zip. The following url where we are directed to register and download the CLI takes me to an error page.

https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/signup.do?source=swg-worklight&S_PKG=ov1268&S_CMP=web_dw_rt_swd is not working properly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. I located a web page where you can download older versions of the CLI. If you are experiencing the same problem with the IBM download page then use the following URL:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/